# Using HTML id to compare to JS variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
var player = {
    su11: 100,
    su22: 1000,
}
function gLoop() {
    $(".upgrade").each(function() {
        var test = player.obj[$(this).attr("id")];

        if(player.total >= test)
        {
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(gLoop, 50);
```

HTML:

```
<button id="su11" class="upgrade su"></button>
```

The current basic code I have is as above. In the html, each instance of the .upgrade class has an id of the format "su##", and the player has a series of values of the same name.

My main concern is how I am using the id to reference the corresponding value in player. Is there an issue with the code that is unrelated to that, or is that simply a very bad idea?

My main goal is a button that, when a value is greater than or equal to its cost, enable itself to be clicked. It would be checked periodically as part of the main game loop. If there's a better way to do this (and I'm almost sure there is), please do tell me; I'm still relatively new to JS/JQuery.

Comment: [Please don't provide images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and please provide a [mcve]. By providing a [mcve] we get the HTML as well which will add important context.

Comment: @JonP Sorry for the picture, I've edited the post.

Comment: Please revert your last edit. By incorporating the solution into your question, the question now makes no sense. If you want to include what you did either add an answer as your own, or **append** it as an update after the main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID tag is used for storing an unique identifier, which can be used to find the element (and no other elements) in the document. Don't store arbitrary information in this tag. It goes against the goal of the ID tag, and also provokes the situation that at a certain time there are multiple elements in the document with the same ID (in a case where multiple elements have the same information payload).

If you really want to connect data to an DOM element, the common way to do it would be to use an `data-xx` attribute with your element such as `<element data-su="12">`, which you could then read with `player.object[$(this).data("su")]`.

Comment: Better still, use  `layer.object[$(this).data("su")]`  see : https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: The ID in this case would be unique to every button - I was intending to 'double down' on the use of it, as the same ID i would be using to access the linked data would be what I use for individual CSS changes. But if the more common approach is to use data- attributes, I will do that instead, thank you.

Comment: It's unfortunately still not seeming to work. Would you have any idea of what would be going wrong?

Comment: What ended up working was simply changing it to player[$(this).data("su")], and having the data-su values equal integers.